# Minha labels ficam abreviadas quando executo programa

Tags: java, swing

Quando executo meu programa o texto que esta dentro de minhas labels ficam abreviados, mesmo tento o espaço necessario, para resolver tenho que deixar um espaço absurdamente grande dentro da label, oque da um baita trabalho para fazer devido ao tamanho do form, queria saber se tem alguma configuração que posso fazer para que isso não ocorra. Exemplos do form no netbeans e do form executado.

[image: dentro do netbeans]

[image: quando executo o programa]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, esse problema existe porque você não setou um tamanho para a sua label, tente dar um setSize com os valores adequados.

Comment: Ele está usando o construtor de GUI do Netbeans.

Comment: Eita é mesmo, e o desenvolvedor não pode mexer no código?
Se não poder nas propriedades deve ter um Width é só modificar la.

Comment: Poder, pode. Mas arrastar/ajustar os componentes ou escrever o código manualmente daria na mesma, ambos usariam o `setSize`. Eu acho que o problema tem a ver com o "layout livre" que o Netbeans usa por padrão, mas não tenho certeza se é isso mesmo, palpite.

Comment: Vocês sabem de algum construtor de GUI sem ser o do netbeans e que seja bom ?